# Project Euler #9: Finding Pythagorean triplets with a given sum

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

### Problem statement:

A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, A < B < C, for which, A² + B² = C².
Given a number N, check if there exists any Pythagorean triplet for which A + B + C = N.

```
public class SpecialPythagoreanTriplet {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scan.nextInt();
    int n=0, i=0, j=0, a=0, b=0, c=0;
    
    while(t!=0) {
        n = scan.nextInt();
        a=0; b=0; c=0;
        for(i=1; i<n; i++)
            for(j=(i+1); j<=n; j++) {
                //These two loops run to take a pair of numbers. j=(i+1) to avoid repetitions in the future.
                if(isSquare((i*i) + (j*j))) //check if a number is a square
                    if(((int)Math.sqrt((i*i)+(j*j)) + i + j) == n) {
                        a = i;
                        b = j;
                        c = (int)Math.sqrt((i*i)+(j*j));
                    }
            }
        if(c==0)
            System.out.println(-1);
        else
            System.out.println(a*b*c);
        t--;
    }
    scan.close();
}

static boolean isSquare(double t) { 
    int a = (int)Math.sqrt(t);
    if(a*a == t)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

I was working on [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler009/problem) program in ProjectEuler and Hackerrank consecutively. It ran perfectly for the input of 1000 and got accepted in Project Euler. But it is giving **Terminated Due to Timeout** error in most of the cases in Hackerrank.

How can I *optimize* it more to evade this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Program terminates due to timeout because of high time complexity, \$O(t*n*n)\$.
Complexity of this program can be reduced to \$O(t)\$ by precomputing and saving the results to avoid repeated computation.

Repeated computation for finding combination of two numbers ( i and j ) can to reduced to execute only once, for a fixed number of times independent of 'n'.

Here is a complete implementation in java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       try{

           //precomputation
           int save[] = new int[3001];

            for(int i=1; i<3001; i++){
               int iSqr = i*i;
               for(int j=i+1; j<3001; j++){

                   double x = Math.sqrt(iSqr + j*j);
                   if(x == Math.floor(x)){
                        int sum     = i+j+(int)x;
                        int product = i*j*(int)x;
                        if((sum < 3001) && (product > save[sum]))
                            save[sum] = product;
                   }
               }              
           }

           int t = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

           while(t-- > 0){
               int n = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
               if(save[n] == 0)
                   System.out.println(-1);
               else
                   System.out.println(save[n]);
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e){

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the mean time, I actually did something like that myself and it worked.

Comment: Happy to know, but do add problem statement next time. @Shadow_Sphynx

Comment: you can do some minor optimistaion if you keep `i` memorized in your loop: `for(int i=1; i<3001; i++){ int iSqr = i*i; ...` and later refer to them in   `double x = Math.sqrt(iSqr + j*j);...` - just cosmetic ^^

Comment: Precomputation makes it `O(n*n)`, not `O(t)`. And other solution is to calculate `b =  (2*n*a-n*n)/(-2*n+2*a)`, that makes it `O(t*n)`, which doesn't make much difference since ranges for `t` and `n` are the same

Comment: O( t + (3000*3001)/2 ) = O(t), since precomputation runs for a constant number of times independent of the program input and can be considered constant in asymptotic notation. Isn't it? @user158037

Comment: O(t + C) where C is a constant is definitely O(t)

Answer (score 4):

**Reorganising the code**

In general, it is a good idea to have your logic computing result and your logic handling output/input as independant as possible. This makes things easier to test, easier to understand and thus easier to optimise. In problems based on Project Euler, this is usually a fairly simple task because the problems are described in such a way that they need little or no input and return a number.

In your case, you could write something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpecialPythagoreanTriplet {

    public static int getProductForPythagoreanTriplerOfPerim(int n)
    {
        int i=0, j=0, a=0, b=0, c=0;
        for(i=1; i<n; i++)
            for(j=(i+1); j<=n; j++) {
                //These two loops run to take a pair of numbers. j=(i+1) to avoid repetitions in the future.
                if(isSquare((i*i) + (j*j))) //check if a number is a square
                    if(((int)Math.sqrt((i*i)+(j*j)) + i + j) == n) {
                        a = i;
                        b = j;
                        c = (int)Math.sqrt((i*i)+(j*j));
                    }
            }
        return (c==0) ? -1 : a*b*c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (false) // interactive
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            for (int t = scan.nextInt(); t!=0; t--) {
                System.out.println(getProductForPythagoreanTriplerOfPerim(scan.nextInt()));
            }
            scan.close();
        }
        else // hardcoded
        {
            System.out.println(getProductForPythagoreanTriplerOfPerim(25) == -1);
            System.out.println(getProductForPythagoreanTriplerOfPerim(1000) == 31875000);
            System.out.println(getProductForPythagoreanTriplerOfPerim(30000) == 1197129472);
        }
    }

    static boolean isSquare(double t) {
        int a = (int)Math.sqrt(t);
        if(a*a == t)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

**Improving the code quality**

Then, a few things you could do to improve your code quality:
 - remove useless comment
 - put brackets around any block containing more than 1 line of code even if this is not required
 - define variables in the smallest possible scope
 - factorise out expressions written and computed multiple times.

You'd get something like:

```
public static int getProductForPythagoreanTriplerOfPerim(int n)
{
    int a=0, b=0, c=0;
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<=n; j++) {
            //These two loops run to take a pair of numbers. j=(i+1) to avoid repetitions in the future.
            int squareCand = i*i + j*j;
            if (isSquare(squareCand)) {
                int squareRoot = (int)Math.sqrt(squareCand);
                if (squareRoot + i + j == n) {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    c = squareRoot;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (c==0) ? -1 : a*b*c;
}
```

**Optimising the code**

Once you've done this. You do not really need the function `isSquare` anymore. For performance reason, it would even be a good idea to get rid of it in order not to compute square roots multiple times.

```
public static int getProductForPythagoreanTriplerOfPerim(int n)
{
    int a=0, b=0, c=0;
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<=n; j++) {
            //These two loops run to take a pair of numbers. j=(i+1) to avoid repetitions in the future.
            int squareCand = i*i + j*j;
            int squareRoot = (int)Math.sqrt(squareCand);
            if (squareRoot*squareRoot == squareCand) {
                if (squareRoot + i + j == n) {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    c = squareRoot;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (c==0) ? -1 : a*b*c;
}
```

Then it is clear that the conditions can be rewritten:

```
           if (squareRoot*squareRoot == squareCand &&
                squareRoot == n - i - j) {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    c = squareRoot;
            }
```

Then you can use this in order not to compute any squareRoot:

```
            int squareRootCand = n - i - j;
            int squareCand = i*i + j*j;
            if (squareRootCand*squareRootCand == squareCand) {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    c = squareRootCand;
            }
```

Also it is even clearer that we want `i + j <= n`. Because `i < j`, we also have `2 * i < n`.
Thus, the loop boundaries can be rewritten:

```
    for (int i=1; 2*i < n; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; i+j<=n; j++) {
```

I think a more precise analysis of the mathematical property would lead to a smaller search space. In fact, because `i` corresponds to the smallest side, we could write: `3 * i < n`and `i + 2j < n`.

*Warning: from here, it's just me trying to apply random (and simple) math operations with no promise whatsoever that things will get better.*

By limiting the number of times sub-expressions are computed, one could write (but I do not find this very beautiful):

```
    int a=0, b=0, c=0;
    for (int i=1; 3*i < n; i++) {
        int i2 = i*i;
        int rem = n-i;
        for (int j=i+1; 2*j<=rem; j++) {
            int squareRootCand = rem - j;
            int squareCand = i2 + j*j;
            if (squareRootCand*squareRootCand == squareCand) {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    c = squareRootCand;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then using mathematical property: `squareRootCand*squareRootCand = (rem - j)^2 = rem^2 -2*rem*j + j^2` and a few simplifications:

```
    for (int i=1; 3*i < n; i++) {
        int i2 = i*i;
        int rem = n-i;
        int rem2 = rem*rem;
        for (int j=i+1; 2*j<=rem; j++) {
            if (rem2 - i2 == 2 * rem * j) {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    c = rem - j;
            }
        }
    }
```

Getting a bit crazy, we can see that we actually want `j == (rem2 - i2) / (2*rem)` and the division to work fine:

```
    for (int i=1; 3*i < n; i++) {
        int i2 = i*i;
        int rem = n-i;
        int rem2 = rem*rem;
        int tmp1 = rem2 - i2;
        int tmp2 = 2 * rem;
        if (tmp1 % tmp2 == 0)
        {
            int tmp3 = tmp1 / tmp2;
            for (int j=i+1; 2*j<=rem; j++) {
                if (tmp3 == j) {
                        a = i;
                        b = j;
                        c = rem - j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and then we do not really need the `j` loop: the code is now a single loop:

```
public static int getProductForPythagoreanTriplerOfPerim(int n) 
{ 
    // a + b + c = n 
    // 0 < a < b < c < n 
    // a^2 + b^2 = c^2 
    int a=0, b=0, c=0; 
    for (int i=1; 3*i < n; i++) { 
        int rem = n-i; 
        int tmp1 = rem*rem - i*i; 
        int tmp2 = 2 * rem; 
        if (tmp1 % tmp2 == 0) 
        { 
            int j = tmp1 / tmp2; 
            if (i+1 <= j && 2*j <= rem) { // not needed ? 
                a = i; 
                b = j; 
                c = rem - j; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return (c==0) ? -1 : a*b*c; 
}
```

Or, making the math more explicit and adding a check for odd values of n:

```
public static int getProductForPythagoreanTriplerOfPerim(int n)
{
    // a + b + c = n  =>  c = n - (a + b)
    // a² + b² = c² becomes:
    // a² + b² = (n - (a + b))² = n² + a² + b² + 2ab - 2n(a+b)
    // 2 b (n - a) = n (n - 2a)
    // we must have n = 2m
    // b = n (n-2a) / (2n -2a) = 2m(2m-2a) / (4m - 2a)
    //   = 2m(m-a) / (2m -a )
    //   = n(m-a) / (n-a)
    int a=0, b=0, c=0;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        int m = n/2;
        for (int i=1; 3*i < n; i++) {
            int top = n*(m-i);
            int down = n-i;
            if (top % down == 0)
            {
                a = i;
                b = top/down;
                c = down - b;
            }
        }
    }
    return (c==0) ? -1 : a*b*c;
}
```

**Going further**

It may not be relevant for this problem (but it may be if you continue on Project Euler problems): a different algorithm can be found using [formulas for generating Pythagoran triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples).